# How to add Scroll bar in div when svg:g is added

Tags: javascript, html, svg, scrollbar

Hi all I am working on html and javascript here is my code

```
<div class = "outer">
 <div class = "inner1 width="234" height="400" style="float: left">
   <svg width="100" height="400" style="float: left;">
      // some thing
   </svg>
 </div>
 <div class = "inner2" width="234" height="400" style="float: left overflow : scroll">
   <svg width="200" height="400" style="float: left;">
      <g class="c1" transform="translate(0,20)">
         <g>
          <text class="c1_name"></text>
          <text class="c1_value"></text>
         </g>

         <g>
          <text class="c2_name"></text>
          <text class="c2_vaue"></text>
         </g>
         <g>
          <text class="c3_name"></text>
          <text class="c3_value"></text>
         </g> 
                    .
                    .
                    . 
         // g added dynamically below the previous one

      </g>
   </svg>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to make my div inner2 scrollable so that when a new g is added and the size of div become small to contain all g it become scrollable.
I have scroll bar appearing but they are disabled also when my new  element come its add but I can not see it.can any one kindly guide me where I am wrong and how to correct this

By the way i am  positioning my  using transform attribute

Thanks

Comment: Check your SVG tags. They don't closes.

Comment: One more problem you got. You need to don't specify height of SVG tag. That to it can grow with your elems being added.

Comment: I have removed height but still. I dont know what am I doing wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `overflow:auto;` if you want to show scrollbar only if it needs.

Comment: the problem is that scroll bar dont get activated

Comment: Maybe that happen becouse you have a lot of sintax errors in your code? Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/3kXty/

Comment: Now you can play with `div` sizes and check your code: http://jsfiddle.net/3kXty/3/

Comment: thanks was only to show actually that is big so i have just added the snippet and change names to make it simple

Comment: Man, if you need to show scrollbar on block with fixed sizes you just need to specify `overflow:auto` CSS rule. Thats it. All problems with your code are in sintax errors.

Answer (score 1):

On `div`, there is no `width` & `height` attribute, use css (eg. `style="width: 999px; height: 999px;"`) and also `overflow: auto` / `overflow: scroll` is needed (you can manipulate each scrollbar independent width `overflow-x` & `overflow-y`).

Comment: Even more, you need to specify measure e.g. `px` in `width` and `heights`.